# Can I use ActiveRecord 3 with Rails 2.3.8?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Can I use ActiveRecord 3 with Rails 2.3.8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly, but I'd strongly suggest against trying it.  The Rails subprojects all release together, and when the full stack is used, it tries to load all components at the same version.